# iOS remoteControlReceivedWithEvent not called

Tags: iphone, ios

In the .plist I have added the normal: http://tinyurl.com/c7e9joy
And when the iPhone is locked or I'm outside the app and open the remote buttons, I can see the app logo and title there, but they don't react.
(I'm testing on my own iPhone.)

```
// Makes sure we are able to connect to the media buttons on the lock screen.
- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder
{
return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void) remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: (UIEvent *) receivedEvent {
NSLog(@"REMOTE");
if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {

    switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {

        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            [self playBtnPressed:nil];

            break;

        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:
            [self skipTrack:nil];
            break;

        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
            [self skipTrack:nil];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are unregistering for the events in viewWillDisapear meaning that anytime that view isn't visible on the phone you wont be registered for the events.  I would change where you register and unregister to the viewDidLoad and viewDidUnload hooks.

Comment: Changed it but still no effect, it doesn't seem to catch the event at all.

Answer (score 2):

You probably also need to add:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

Any subclass of `UIResponder` needs to implement this, or it won't accept first responder status.